# How to serve an animated plotly-express figure in dash?

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-express

I tried to show this example from the plotly-exress homepage in dash.

```
import plotly.express as px
gapminder = px.data.gapminder()
px.scatter(gapminder, x="gdpPercap", y="lifeExp", animation_frame="year", animation_group="country",
           size="pop", color="continent", hover_name="country",
           log_x=True, size_max=55, range_x=[100,100000], range_y=[25,90])
```

Like this:

```
import plotly_express as px
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

gapminder = px.data.gapminder()

dimensions = []

app = dash.Dash(
    __name__, external_stylesheets=["https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css"]
)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.H1("Gapminder data"),
        dcc.Graph(id="graph", style={"width": "75%", "display": "inline-block"}),
    ]
)

@app.callback(Output("graph", "figure"), [])
def make_figure():
    return px.scatter(gapminder, x="gdpPercap", y="lifeExp", animation_frame="year", animation_group="country",
                      size="pop", color="continent", hover_name="country",
                      log_x=True, size_max=55, range_x=[100,100000], range_y=[25,90])


app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Though, only an empty figure shows up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: you need the latest version of Dash and Dash Core Components to render animation frames.

In this case it's because your callback never fires, because the second argument is an empty list (i.e. it doesn't depend on any inputs).

If you inline the figure into the layout, it will render:

```
import plotly_express as px
import dash
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_core_components as dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output

gapminder = px.data.gapminder()

dimensions = []

app = dash.Dash(
    __name__, external_stylesheets=["https://codepen.io/chriddyp/pen/bWLwgP.css"]
)

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.H1("Gapminder data"),
        dcc.Graph(id="graph", style={"width": "75%", "display": "inline-block"},
        figure=px.scatter(gapminder, x="gdpPercap", y="lifeExp", animation_frame="year", animation_group="country",
                      size="pop", color="continent", hover_name="country",
                      log_x=True, size_max=55, range_x=[100,100000], range_y=[25,90])),
    ]
)


app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Or you could wire up you callback to depend on an input that does change, and it will fire and populate the figure :)

Comment: Are you using the latest version of dash, which is 1.0.x, and the corresponding version of dash_core_components? These together work for me. I added frames support to dcc.Graph a few weeks ago.

Comment: No, I am using '0.39.0' which seems to be the latest version available on the conda channel... Why do I have to specify dash=1 to get the newest version? Instead this outdated version is installed...

Comment: I’m not sure why conda does this, sorry :) maybe because it’s a major version change from 0.x to 1.x?

Comment: If you don’t want to go all the way to 1.0, I checked and the the frames support was added to dash-core-components in version 0.48: https://github.com/plotly/dash-core-components/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md

Comment: Great! Feel free to accept the answer if it helped you :)

Comment: I am getting the frame in an unordered way.Is there any way to order the animation slider.For example, I get the values on slider as (3,2,1,4).Instead I want like (1,2,3,4)

Comment: Try sorting your dataframe accordingly before creating the figure.